# C++ call methods in the context of main thread from a sub thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, opengl

Im trying to setup a multithreaded mesh generations with OpenGL. I have read that the best thing to do is to have the subthreads call openGL through the main thread. What i cant figure out is how to do it.

I tried creating a singelton object in the main thread and then accessing it in the subthreads(c++ future), it didnt work. Then i tried just makeing a static class but that also didnt work.

How do i setup it such a way that i can have subthreads invoke openGL methods thorugh main thread?

Comment: You need your main thread to act as a server that accepts requests from other threads and executes them. Anything could be a request transport mechanism, but a simple multi-producer, single-consumer queue (suitably protected by mutexes and condition variables) should work.

Comment: It also depends what you want to do in the subthreads. If it's mostly about object creation and data upload, I suggest using shared OpenGL contexts which allow you to make OpenGL calls from different threads. If you really need to modify the state or perform rendering commands, then what n.m. suggest is probably your best bet, but I wouldn't expect too much performance wise.

Comment: @BDL So i created multiple contexts and i am binding them at the beginning of the std::future. But all the buffers are always 0.

Comment: Did you create a **shared** OpenGL context? What do you mean by "the buffers are null"? Which code are you calling and where does it return 0.

Comment: Im using SDL2. It has a attrobute `SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_SHARE_WITH_CURRENT_CONTEXT, 1);`  that should turn on sharing. And then i can use `SDL_GL_CreateContext(window)` to make contexts and `SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(window, gContext)` to activate contexts. Now calling `glGenBuffers` does not create buffer on the thread. It should set the GLuint to some value other than 0. But all the buffers are always 0.